# Trying to implement text and a video using .innerhtml in modal boostrap

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal

I am having trouble implementing a bootstrap modal that will showcase text and embed a video at the bottom of the modal.

```
<h3 id = "giza_Pyramid" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Chatgpt";>The Giza Pyramids</h3>

const strText1 = `The Giza Pyramids, built to...`;

if (
  document
    .getElementById("giza_Pyramid")
    .addEventListener("click", function () {
      document.querySelector("#modal_title").textContent = "Pyramids of Giza";
      document.querySelector("#modal_body").textContent = strText1;
      document.querySelector("#modal_body").innerHTML =
        '<video class ="giza_Pyramid" width = "450" height = "350" controls src= "Media/gizapyramids.mp4"></video>';
    })
);
```

I currently am using .textcontent to show the text and use .innerhtml to embed the video but what ends up showing is the video alone. What should end up being shown is text and then at the bottom of the modal there should be a video

Comment: .innerHTML (like textContent) *replaces* the entire content - one allows HTML, the other does not, but otherwise they do the same thing.  Change to `.innerHTML = strText1 + '<video...` - ie add them both at the same time.  Or use `.append()`

Comment: This is expected as you override modal_body div with textContent first and then innerHTML. you can have two divs inside model and then add video and text seperately